# Docker build is not using cache all the time for react/node project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, jenkins, dockerfile

I have a docker file for deploying my react project. Here is the `dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:14.2.0

COPY package.json /tmp/package.json
RUN cd /tmp && npm install --silent
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/ && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /home/node/app/

WORKDIR /home/node/app/
USER root
COPY . ./
```

I believe if there is no change in `package.json` it will use cache for npm install`(2nd step)` and copying node_modules `(3rd step)`.

But even if there is no change in `package.json` it does not.
How do I cache the steps then ?

Comment: how are you creating the container? You just showed how you made the image.